# how to import module 'child_process' on server side of a ReactJS app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, require, child-process

How does one use a module like 'child_process' from a ReactJS app?
(react@16.3.1 / Linux)

These syntaxes fail:

```
import { spawn } from 'child_process'
const ls = spawn('ls', ['-al']);
```

yields:  `TypeError: Object(...) is not a function`

```
import cp from 'child_process';
const ls = cp.spawn('ls', ['-al']);
```

yields:  `TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_child_process___default.a.spawn is not a function`

```
var { spawn } = require('child_process');
const ls = spawn('ls', ['-al']);
```

yields:  `TypeError: spawn is not a function`

Comment: What's your use case exactly ?

Comment: Sorry my question was poorly formulated: my app actually has server-side code (where the exception happens) but the error had nothing to do with React. I finally found a way to import module child_process.there. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use node's module `child_process` in a react application.

You can't access to OS system processes to spawn and fork from browser because it's an isolated environment.

Comment: Still, a part of the React app is running on the server side: is it possible to spawn the child process on the server side?

Comment: Even if you are using SSR on server, you can't and I don't see any use case where you want to use react to spawn a child process. Use node.js to spawn process, do the calculation and send them to react (which is a library to show received data from server to DOM). React can only provide functionalities that are supported by browsers. (Accessing client OS and spawn processes is not allowed by browsers for security reasons).

Answer (score 3):

ReactJS is only working on the client side of you app and interacting with the DOM. Child processes are fired on the server side of your app.

So those two thing are separated.

ReactJS could make an http call for example to the server that will then trigger the child process. The server could send the results of the child process back to the React client.